# Tratamento de erro em C#!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Galera, é o seguinte, em minha aplicação eu gostaria que fosse exibido uma página com o erro ocorrido, mas que essa página tenha toda a formatação proposta no layout, portanto isso não ta ocorrendo, pois apenas gera uma página toda em branco com o código do erro. Abaixo os código que estou usando:

No homeController:

```
public ActionResult ExemploErroNaoMapeado()
        {
            var response = new ResponseViewModel();
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Oops, ocorreu um erro");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return ErroCapturado(e);
            }
            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult ErroCapturado(Exception ex)
        {
            var response = new ResponseViewModel
            {
                Data = ex.Data,
                Sucesso = false,
                Mensagem = ex.Message
            };

            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Em manageViewModels adicionei:

```
 public class ResponseViewModel
    {
        public object Data { get; set; }
        public bool Sucesso { get; set; }
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    }
```

E a página que deve exibir o erro ta assim:

```
<h2>
    Ocorreu um erro não mapeado durante a execução
    da última ação...
</h2>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //debugger;
        gerandoRelatorio();
        function gerandoRelatorio() {
            $.getJSON("Home/ExemploErroNaoMapeado", function (response) {

                if (response.sucesso) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.mensagem);
                }

            }).fail(function (response) {
                //Erro genérico
                alert("Não foi possível processar a sua requisição");

            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Portanto quero saber, como fazer o layout funcionar nessa página, já que ela carrega toda em branco e nem sequer traz o menu junto?

Com as alterações sugeridas pelo amigo abaixo esta aparecendo esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou colocar aqui os passos, e uma mudança no seu controller:

1. Verificou se essa view está com o mesmo nome da sua action?

   - Se não estiver, precisa estar pois se não não vai retornar.
2. Para retornar a view, você tem que retornar não um JsonResult, mas sim uma view com o model do erro.

   - O que acontece é que um JsonResult é mais usado quando você faz chamadas ajax para o controller. Se for uma chamada comum, mude para outro ActionResult, ou faça um RedirectToAction, que volte uma view de erro;

Faça da seguinte forma para ver se dá certo:

```
public ActionResult ExemploErroNaoMapeado()
{
    var response = new ResponseViewModel();
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Oops, ocorreu um erro");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ErroCapturado", e);
    }
    return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult ErroCapturado(Exception ex)
{
    var response = new ResponseViewModel
    {
        Data = ex.Data,
        Sucesso = false,
        Mensagem = ex.Message
    };

    return View(response);

}
```

3. A página não tem declaração de layout, nem de model, por isso retorna em branco.

   Acrescente o seguinte código no começo da sua view, não esquecendo de colocar o namespace antes da classe no model:

   ```
   @{
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";    
   }
   @model ResponseViewModel
   ```

Comment: Não deu certo, apareceu o erro "Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated. "

Comment: Qual a exception? Poderia colocar uma imagem dela, ou acrescentar a sua pergunta os detalhes da exception?

Comment: editei a pergunta colocando a imagem do erro, veja lá.... cara isso ta quebrando a minha cabeça.... n sei mais o que fazer, ainda mais que estou iniciando agora com C#, vim do PHP!

Comment: Vai depurando o codigo, e quando der a exception, coloca o stacktrace dela, por favor.